# Magento Add to cart not working

Tags: magento

Writting custom script to add product to particular customer.

In this way.

```
                 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

                $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
                $cart->truncate();
                $cart->save();
                $cart->getItems()->clear()->save();                 
                $req = Mage::app()->getRequest(); 
                $request['qty'] = $selected_qty[$i]; 
                $request['product'] = $value;               

                $prod_req = new Varien_Object($request);                
                try {       
                    $cart->addProduct($product, $prod_req);
                    $cart->save();  
                    $msg .= "<p>".$product->getName(). " ==> ".$selected_qty[$i] . " items <br/></p>";                      
                }
                catch (Exception $ex) {
                    $err .= "<p>".$ex->getMessage(). " <br/></p>";;
                }
```

Customer session shows logged in customer details, but this doesn't adding the product to the cart. Whats the problem, could anyone find out.

Thanks

Comment: what exception message is output?

Comment: no error or no exception. just going through next lines..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by in the same way from inchoo site. Thanks to them.

Here is what i have now.

```
$product =   Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($value);                   
                $cart    = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');

                $params = array(
                    'product' => $value,
                    'related_product' => null,                  
                    'qty' => $selected_qty[$i],
                );      

                try {       
                    $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
                    $cart->getItems()->save();               
                    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);                
                    $msg .= "<p>".$product->getName(). " ==> ".$selected_qty[$i] . " item(s) <br/></p>";                        
                }
                catch (Exception $ex) {
                    $err .= "<p>".$ex->getMessage(). " <br/></p>";;
                }
```

Its working perfectly.